# Could you use a Shrinking Solution on a basilisk?

Tags: harry-potter, potions

According to what I've read, the Shrinking Solution makes things smaller/younger (Neville's toad Trevor turns into a tadpole). Is there any evidence to suggest that this potion wouldn't work on a creature like the basilisk?

Comment: There is no evidence to suggest either way, but I suppose no, because most powerfully magical creatures in Harry Potter are immune to general types of magic

Answer (score 1):

### I see no reason why not.

You may or may not need a larger dose to transform a Basilisk but I see no reason why it wouldn't work. The passage you mention is the only one I recall where Shrinking Solutions come up.

> Snape picked up Trevor the toad in his left hand, and dipped a small spoon into Neville's potion, which was now green. He trickled **a few drops** down Trevor's throat.
>   <sub>*(Prisoner of Azkaban, Chapter 7, The Boggart in the Wardrobe)*</sub>

Since scale seems to matter in Harry Potter (transforming smaller objects is easier than transforming big ones, and so on) it would be reasonable to assume that you'd need more than a few drops to shrink a Basilisk. However, there's nothing about either the potion or the nature of a Basilisk that I'm aware of that means that it wouldn't work.

What would the Basilisk transform into? Once again, the only parallel we have is Trevor.

> There was a moment of hushed silence, in which Trevor gulped; then there was a small *pop*, and Trevor the tadpole was wriggling in Snape's palm.
>   <sub>*(Prisoner of Azkaban, Chapter 7, The Boggart in the Wardrobe)*</sub>

From this we can gather that a Shrinking Solution makes its target both *smaller* and *younger*. The Basilisk would presumably either turn into a much smaller snake, or return to being an egg.

### That said, it wouldn't be a good idea.

The principle is the same with using any spell on a highly dangerous creature. It's the same conundrum that Harry faced when deciding how to tackle his dragon in *Goblet of Fire*. There are plenty of spells you *could* use against a Basilisk or a dragon but not many that would take effect quickly enough to let you live to tell the tale. If the Basilisk was asleep then you could probably Shrink it very effectively.

But would it be an effective defence strategy against an alert, aggresive Basilisk, even if you had the Solution to hand? Absolutely not. It would kill you with its death ray stare before you got your hand to your pocket.